# How to get value from combobox assign to button and navigate to next screen in Powerapps?

Tags: powerapps

How to get value from combobox assign to button and navigate to next screen in Powerapps?

My Next Button OnSelect Code:

```
Navigate(UpdateTypeComboBox.Selected.Update_Type,ScreenTransition.None)
```

It show me the functions navigate have an invalid argument.

Please advice thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
Navigate(Screen1, ScreenTransition.None, {comboval: UpdateTypeComboBox.Selected.Value1})
```

where **Screen1** is the screen you are passing the value to and **ScreenTransition.None** is the screen transition and **comboval** is a contextual variable in which you are assigning the value from **UpdateTypeComboBox** to.

Note that you should have assigned this variable "**comboval**" to the label or text field where you are passing it to.
For example, if it's a label, in the Text property of the label, just input "**comboval**"

Let me know if you have any issue with this